# Node.js Swagger - using multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

I'm building the Express.js application which uses Swagger to define endpoints. The problem is that by project specification I need to be able to work with multiple swagger files (each one will have it's own `basePath`) to define endpoints for various services. Is it possible to make such an interaction with Swagger?

Comment: I am just curious, why don't you use Express to define endpoints. That is what Express is for.

Comment: I'd definitely used it, but unfortunately I'm just following the requirements. There isn't much helpful information out there in the web, I wonder if someone could have faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools) solved my question. I've created the pipeline recursively after parsing each swagger file.